# Executing a transaction on neo4j it does not apply to the original graph

Tags: transactions, neo4j

I have a graph that show people (Leitor) that know (Conhece) other people. So I created a trasaction at the cypher console like this:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "CREATE (Matheus:Leitor {nome:'Matheus', completo:'Matheus Silva'}) CREATE (Gutierrez)-[:Conhece]->(Matheus) CREATE (Matheus)-[:Conhece]->(Gutierrez) CREATE (Jose:Leitor {nome:'Jose', completo:'Jose Silva'}) CREATE (Jose)-[:Conhece]->(Matheus) CREATE (Matheus)-[:Conhece]->(Jose) RETURN Matheus"
  } ]
}
```

But the final result the person (Leitor) Gutierrez does not know Matheus. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the single query you are using to create the graph, then the problem is that you don't have a `CREATE` statement defining the properties for the Node Gutierrez. For Gutierrez there is only `CREATE (Gutierrez)-[:Conhece]->(Matheus)` and `CREATE (Matheus)-[:Conhece]->(Gutierrez)`, referring to a variable called "Gutierrez". Since nothing is bound to this variable, the first time you use it will create a blank Node in the graph and bind that blank node to the variable "Gutierrez".

You have a few ways to fix this. One is to simple add a `CREATE` statement for Gutierrez at the beginning of your query:

```
CREATE (Gutierrez:Leitor {nome:'Gutierrez', completo: 'Full Name Here'})
...
```

This will create the node with the properties defined above and bind that node to the variable "Gutierrez" for the rest of the query.

If the data might already exist in the graph however you might want to use a [`MERGE`statement](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) instead of `CREATE`:

```
MERGE (Gutierrez:Leitor {nome:'Gutierrez'})
ON CREATE SET Gitierrez.completo = 'Full Name Here'
MERGE (Matheus:Leitor {nome:'Matheus'})
ON CREATE SET Matheus.completo = 'Matheus Silva'
...
```

`MERGE` acts as a "get or create" and will look for Nodes already in the graph matching the pattern. If the node matching the criteria in the `MERGE` statement already exists, the variable will be bound to that node. If not then a new node will be created.